# Generic list typecasting problem

Tags: c#, linq, silverlight, ado.net-entity-data-model

I'm new to C# and am stuck on the following. I have a Silverlight web service that uses LINQ to query a ADO.NET entity object. e.g.:

```
[OperationContract]
public List<Customer> GetData()
{
    using (TestEntities ctx = new TestEntities())
    {
        var data = from rec in ctx.Customer
                   select rec;
        return data.ToList();
    }
}
```

This works fine, but what I want to do is to make this more abstract. The first step would be to return a `List<EntityObject>` but this gives a compiler error, e.g.:

```
[OperationContract]
public List<EntityObject> GetData()
{
    using (TestEntities ctx = new TestEntities())
    {
        var data = from rec in ctx.Customer
                   select rec;
        return data.ToList();
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SilverlightTest.Web.Customer>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 3):

Even though `Customer` inherits from `EntityObject`, `List<Customer>` doesn't inherit from `List<EntityObject>`, because generic type covariance is not supported (in C# 4.0, covariance is supported for interfaces, but not for `IList<T>`).

If you could assign a `List<Customer>` to a variable of type `List<EntityObject>`, it would allow you to do something like that :

```
List<EntityObject> list = new List<Customer>();
list.Add(new Product()); // assuming Product inherits from EntityObject
```

This code is obviously broken : you can't add a `Product` to a `List<Customer>`. That's why it's not allowed

Answer (score 0):

```
[OperationContract]
public List<EntityObject> GetData()
{
    using (TestEntities ctx = new TestEntities())
    {
        var data = from rec in ctx.Customer
                   select (EntityObject)rec;
        return data.ToList();
    }
}
```

you can't cast List to List even if D derives from B. It is called covariance and works with arrays only. It will be fully introduced in C# 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Your var data contains Customer objects, your return is a list with EntityObjects.

You'll have to cast them:

```
data.ConvertAll(obj => (EntityObject) obj).ToList();
```

Comment: I like this, but it didn't work for me as data does not have a ConvertAll method.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
data.Cast<EntityObject>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the `data.Cast<EntityObject>().ToList();`, you will probably need to define the derived types on as know types, so WCF will know how to serialize the derived objects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx